# Spring Kafka No method found for java.util.LinkedHashMap

Tags: json, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a Spring Boot Kafka listener that looks like this:

```
@Component
@KafkaListener(topics = "mytopic")
public class EventListener {
    
    @Jacksonized
    @Builder
    @Value
    @With
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    public static class Event {
        private final String id;
    }

    @KafkaHandler
    public void listen(Event event) {
        System.out.println("processing single event: " + event.toString());
    }

    @KafkaHandler
    public void listenBatch(List<Event> events) {
        System.out.println("processing " + events.size() + " events");
    }
}
```

With a configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public RecordMessageConverter converter() { 
        return new JsonMessageConverter(); 
    }

    @Bean
    public BatchMessagingMessageConverter batchConverter() { 
      return new BatchMessagingMessageConverter(converter());
    }
}
```

When I push messages into the topic, this data works fine, and triggers the listenBatch

```
[{"id": "123"}]
```

but this kind of data

```
{"id": "123"}
```

throws an exception:

```
org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener failed; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: No method found for class java.util.LinkedHashMap
```

Is there any way I can get this to work?

Comment: If the payload is already a HashMap, it probably means you are using a `JsonDeserializer`; when using the message converter, you should use a `ByteArrayDeserializer`. Furthermore, you can't mix batch Vs. record listeners in the same `@KafkaListener` class.

Comment: A single JSON object isn't a list that can be accepted by the batch handler. If you look at more of the stacktrace should be clear which handler is used

Comment: Is there any way I can have a single listener accept both `List<Event>` and `Event`?